# index.html doesn't show up in app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I am working on an android app.
Everytime when I add this:

`super.loadUrl("assets/www/index.html");`

My app just show the standard:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Also my `import android.app.Activity;` goes to a never used status when I add this:

`import org.apache.cordova.*;`

I hope someone could help me out.
And excuse me if something is missing. This is my first question here.

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using? If you are using the latest version, 3.0, you don't really need to mess with the Java at all, see the Android guide here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide
If you are using, say, 2.7/2.8, you would use `super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl()`; if it's 2.6, you'd use `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")`. Take a look at the guides, and make sure that the version of the guide matches the version of Cordova you are using (change it in the top right drop down.)

Comment: Thank you! I use cordova 2.9.0